# How to allow only one user to be able to access only one pod within an openshift project?

Tags: openshift, rbac, kubernetes-rbac, cri-o

I need solve an issue about pod access inside a given project.

One given user, just need to do `oc exec` in a specific pod, inside a specific project.

The user has the lowest rbac profile inside the cluster.

Was assigned the admin role to user. This do with user just access the project, but don't limit the access to a only pod.

I created a role like this

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: role-teste-access-pod
  namespace: <project>
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - pods
    verbs:
      - create
```

Then I did:

```
oc apply -f role-teste-access-pod.yaml
#role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/role-teste-access-pod created

oc adm policy add-role-to-user role-teste-access-pod caueteste -n <project>
#clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/role-teste-access-pod added: "caueteste"
```

So, I log me with user, access the project, execute `oc exec`, but the message is shown.

```
# oc exec -n <project> -it <pod> -c <container> -- bash
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "<pod>" is forbidden: User "caueteste" cannot create resource "pods/exec" in API group "" in the namespace "<project>": RBAC: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "role-teste-access-pod" not found
[caueteste@localhost]$
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating a function and then a function binding as follows below

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: role-teste-access-pod
  namespace: <project_name>
rules:
apiGroups: ['', "extensions", "apps"]
resources: ["pods", "pods/exec"]
resourceNames: ["pod_name"]
verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create"]
```

---

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: role-teste-access-pod-bind
  namespace: <project_name>
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User_or_Group
  name: user_or_group_name
  namespace: <project_name>
roleRef:
kind: Role
name: role-teste-access-pod
apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Regards